# AWS C++ code run on EC2 (cloud vs traditional computing)

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, runtime

My question is very simple although I could not find answer online.

Currently I'm using EC2 just for proof of concept. I'm Running the Bubble Sort algorithm in C++ with variable integer array size and counting how much time the program takes to finish the ordering either on EC2 and on my computer.

I know C++ is not a default language to be used on the cloud, so like on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128209 I just connected by ssh and installed the needed packages to run my C++ program.

However the expected gains against traditional computing where not as good as in Python for example... Anyone knows if there is a way of improving these gains? All timing info info bellow.

[Execution times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bW6s.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
From [AWS EC2 Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/):

> **Considerations for Amazon EC2 performance evaluation**
>
> Amazon EC2 provides you with a large number of options across ten different instance types, each with one or more size options, organized into six distinct instance families optimized for different types of applications. We recommend that you assess the requirements of your applications and select the appropriate instance family as a starting point for application performance testing. You should start evaluating the performance of your applications by (a) identifying how your application needs compare to different instance families (e.g. is the application compute-bound, memory-bound, etc.?), and (b) sizing your workload to identify the appropriate instance size. There is no substitute for measuring the performance of your full application since application performance can be impacted by the underlying infrastructure or by software and architectural limitations. We recommend application-level testing, including the use of application profiling and load testing tools and services.

Here are 7 different ways to change your EC2 instances to gain performance (from link above):

### General Purpose EC2 instances:

T2 prefixed instances have burstable performance, M4 and M3 prefixes have balanced between compute/memory/network.

### EC2 instances that are compute optimized:

Instances with higher performing processors.  Instance names with prefix C4 and C3.

### EC2 instances that are memory optimized:

Instances optimized for in memory applications. Instance names with prefix with X1, R4 and R3.

### EC2 instances with accelerated computing:

Instances optimized for GPU processing (P2 name prefix), Graphics processing (G2 name prefix) field programmable gate arrays (F2 name prefix)

### EC2 instances with storage optimization:

High storage instances (I3 prefix) and dense storage (D2 prefix)

### EC2 instances with dedicated tenacy:

The tenancy option determines if your EC2 instance is on shared hardware in the cloud with other AWS customers.  Shared tenancy is the default for all EC2 instances.  The other option would be Dedicated Instances and Dedicated Hosts.  For a higher price you can pay Amazon to host your EC2 instances on single tenant hardware.

### Load a different AMI/Compiler combo:

There are many variations on Operating Systems to choose from (Windows, Unix, Linux, etc).  You might also choose between different [C++ compilers](http://www.stroustrup.com/compilers.html) with [many optimizations to choose](http://insights.dice.com/2013/11/04/speed-test-comparing-intel-c-gnu-c-and-llvm-clang-compilers/).

These 7 can be combined with each other in an effort to get the most improvements.  This [website can better help you determine cost vs EC2 feature to AWS region](http://www.ec2instances.info/?region=eu-central-1).

Good luck and feel free to post the results you discover.  Thanks!